# Flex application UI is gone and instead there is a completely white background?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

My Flex application has seemingly disappeared. When I run the application it is showing a completely white background. There are no errors and it was working previously. I've ran clean and stepped back through my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is I set the ID a component in my Application to "contentGroup". Even though no error was thrown this ID is used by the application and the application skin.

```
<components:ContentGroup id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

To fix it use another ID:

```
<components:ContentGroup id="mainContentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" />
```